# Ideals that are not principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the following ideals are NOT principal ideals:

(a.) I ⊂ Z[x], the ideal consisting of all polynomials such that f(0) is even.

I need to create a set which contains this ideal I and its elements are f(x) s.t f(0) is even then show that there is no $h(x)$ belong to $Z[x]$ s.t $I= <h(x)>$.

(b.) I ⊂ R[x, y], the ideal consisting of all polynomials f(x, y) ∈ R[x, y] such that f(0, 0) = 0.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe it helps to notice that in case (a): $I=\langle 2,x\rangle$ and in case (b): $I=\langle x,y\rangle$ so that you know the form of elements in $I$.

Comment: I assumed for a contradiction that I is a principal ideal.  Then there would be a generator g(x) . Then I found that when we show that the ideal I is a subset of the ideal generated by g(x) ,, I take f(x)=2a as a constant polynomial with degree 0. Then I found that g(x).h(x) should be a constant polynomials ,,,but I am still confused

Answer (score 0):

As in your comment, assume $I$ is principally generated by $g(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Since the constant polynomial $f(x)=2$ satisfies $f(0)$ is even, it follows that $2=g(x)h(x)$ for some $h(x)$. Taking degrees, we have $0=\deg 2 = \deg gh = \deg g+\deg h$, so $\deg g=\deg h=0$. From this you conclude that $g(x)=\pm 2$.

But now, the polynomial $f(x)=2+x\in I$, so $f(x)=2h(x)$ for some $h(x)$, which is impossible. Therefore, there is no such $g(x)$.

A similar argument will work in the other case.

Comment: Wow thank you so much,   I am still struggling with 2 because I took f(x,y)= x+y then I found the degree for the generator should be at least 1 then I could not complete

Comment: If $\deg g +\deg h\geq 1$ what can you conclude.

Comment: Ok do you mean that the constant polynomial f(x,y)=0 belong to the ideal I since f(0,0)=0 for the polynomial f(x,y)=0. So there is a contradiction since  degg+degh (must be)≥1??? is that true

Comment: No, but $f(x,y)=x$ belongs to the ideal, as does $f(x,y)=y$.